# How to access data on Perl Object structures

Tags: json, perl, object

I have the following perl code in where I have a perl structure as follows:
`

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %data = (
  'status' => 200,
  'message' => '',
  'response' => {
    'name' => 'John Smith',
    'id' => '1abc579',
    'ibge' => '3304557',
    'uf' => 'XY',
    'status' => bless( do{\(my $o = 1)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' )
  }

);

my $resp = $data{'status'};
print "Response is $resp \n";
print Dumper(%data->{'response'});
```

Getting the status field works, however If I try something like this:
`my $resp = $data{'response'}`

I get Response is HASH(0x8b6640)

So I'm wondering if there's a way I can extract **all** the data of the 'response' field on the same way I can do it for 'status' without getting that HASH...

I've tried all sort of combinations when accessing the data, however I'm still getting the HASH back when I try to get the content of 'response'

Comment: Read through https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc and https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut

Answer (score 1):

`$data{'response'}` is the correct way to access that field on a hash called `%data`. It's returning a hash reference, which prints out by default in the (relatively unhelpful) `HASH(0x8b6640)` syntax you've seen. But if you pass that reference to `Dumper`, it'll show you everything.

```
print Dumper($data{'response'});
```

to actually *access* those subfields, you need to dereference, which is done with an indirection `->` operation.

```
print $data{'response'}->{'name'}
```

The first access doesn't need the `->` because you're accessing a field on a hash *variable* (i.e. a variable with the `%` sigil). The second one does because you're dereferencing a reference, which, at least in spirit, has the `$` sigil like other scalars.

Comment: You don't need the `->`. It can be written as `$data{'response'}->{'name'}`.

Comment: Also, note that `$data{response}` has the `$` sigil because it's a single element access to a hash. The reference stuff has nothing to do with that `$`.

Comment: use Data::Dumper;

my %data = (
  'status' => 200,
  'message' => '',
  'response' => {
    'name' => 'John Smith',
    'id' => '1abc579',
    'ibge' => '3304557',
    'uf' => 'XY',
    'status' => bless( do{\(my $o = 1)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' )
  }

);

my $resp = $data{'response'};
print Dumper($resp);

Comment: @briandfoy "Isn't" perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your posts. I fixed the code as follows:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %data = (
  'status' => 200,
  'message' => '',
  'response' => {
    'name' => 'John Smith',
    'id' => '1abc579',
    'ibge' => '3304557',
    'uf' => 'XY',
    'status' => bless( do{\(my $o = 1)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' )
  }

);

my $resp = $data{'response'};
print Dumper($resp);
```

Now it works like a charm, and I'm able to get the data I want.